# Cohomology of zero dimensional sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let,$E$ be a zero dimensional sheaf on an algebraic surface $S$ over the field of complex numbers,i.e $dim(Supp(E)) =0$

Then my question is the following : Is it true that $H^{1}(E) =0$ or in general $H^{i}(E) =0$ for all $i \geq 1$?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: Higher cohomology of a flabby sheaf is trivial (or in other words flabby sheaves are acyclic). Coherent sheaves with zero dimensional supports are flabby.

Comment: @Slup, could please elaborate(or perhaps give me a reference) " coherent sheaves with zero dimensional supports are flabby"

Comment: Think of the most simple case : $Supp(E)$ is a single reduced point $x$, then $E$ is just a skyscraper sheaf, that is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space concentrated in $\{x\}$. The transition maps $E(U) \to E(V)$ are either $0$ or the identity. Hence $E$ is flabby. You can try to generalize to the general case.

Comment: @Dominique Mattei, Since $E$ is a sheaf can we not say from espace etale of a presheaf that for any open $U$, $E(U)$ is the space of sections $ s : U \to \cup_{p \in U} E_p$ and with respect to that interpretation the map $E(V) \to E(U)$ becomes surjective for the inclusion $U \subset V$(taking into account the fact that at only finitely many points the stalk is nonzero)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I develop my comment here. I assume your sheaf is coherent as you are interested in algebraic surfaces.

Thus let $E$ be a coherent sheaf on an algebraic variety. Assume $Supp(E)=\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is finite. Write $E(x_j)$ the stalk of $E$ at $x_j$. The restriction map $E\to E^{'}:=\oplus_j E(x_j)$ is an isomorphism of sheaves as it is an isomorphism on each stalk.

Let $U\in X$ be an open and let $x_{i_1},\dots x_{i_k}$ be the subset of $x_i$'s lying in $U$. Then the sheaf $E^{'}$ verifies
$$E^{'}(X) = E(x_1)\oplus \cdots \oplus E(x_n)$$
and
$$E^{'}(U)= E(x_{i_1})\oplus \cdots \oplus  E(x_{i_k})$$
and the transition map $E^{'}(X) \to E^{'}(U)$ is given by the projection
$$E'(X) \to E'(U), (a_1,\dots, a_n) \mapsto (a_{i_1},\dots, a_{i_k})$$
which is clearly surjective.

Finally you can check that if $E'(X)\to E'(U)$ is surjective for all open subset $U$ then the sheaf is flabby.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly then you are defining a new sheaf $E'$ out of $E$ which is isomorphic to $E$ and then showing that  $E^{'}(X) \to E^{'}(U)$ is surjective ,which means $E(X) \to E(U)$ is surjective using the previous sheaf isomorphism, from where it follows that $E$ is flabby.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right, i editted my answer because I forgot some "$'$", but an isomorphism of sheaves leads to isomorphisms over every open so $E$ and $E^{'}$ are really the same sheaves.

Answer (score 1):

This can be also viewed as a consequence of a general fact due to Grothendieck (which can be proved by noetherian induction).

*Let $X$ be a noetherian topological space of dimension $n$. Then for all $i>n$ and all sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ of abelian groups on $X$ we have $\mathrm{H}^i(X,\mathcal{F}) = 0$.*

For this fact c.f. Hartshorne's **Algebraic Geometry, chapter III, Theorem 2.7**. The proof uses the fact (as a basis of induction) that on zero dimensional neotherian spaces (on finite discrete spaces) all higher cohomologies of sheaves vanish. So the best approach to your question is showing that sheaves on zero dimensional noetherian spaces are flabby.